# Can I have multiple outside LED strip lights coming from one driver?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I'm in the process of buying LED strip lights and understand that I need a 'driver' (to convert from 240v to [whatever the strip lights are]).

I intend to have three strip lights, one for each step outside, so do I need three drivers or can one driver do all three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strips are intended for "12VDC" then they require a constant voltage supply. This is the usual arrangement for strips. In this case:

- check how much current each strip will use
- multiply by the number of strips
- get a 12VDC supply with more amps than what you need, like a wall wart or a "led driver" specified to output 12V (which is not really a driver in this case, since it is a constant voltage supply) .
- wire all the strips in parallel

If your strips are not specified for 12V but instead should be driven by constant current then you will need a constant current driver per strip. This would be uncommon.